# .htaccess file permissions changed

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, hacking

I have a weird problem on some of my servers with Directadmin and Wordpress installed. The file permissions of the .htaccess file are set to 444. When I change them back to 644, edit the file and save it, it is changed to the former again.

So the content is the same as before, with the permissions set to 444. It seems as though some sort of script is changing the file permissions. Could this be malware on the server? Or would my site in other ways be compromised?

Comment: Thre're some plugins for security, that change permission. But usually the opposite way. That is, put the .htaccess to 444 or 400 depending on the Web Server + PHP model. It is strange.When you edit the file and you go back to change the permissions, you verify that you change? ls? with an FTP program? Are you sure that the information you see is correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is persisting you could try to turn off any plugins you think might be causing the problem and activate them one by one to see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Do you think a WordPress plugin is doing this, then? It seems unlikely, but maybe it's possible...

Comment: A plugin could have conflicting code or malware so it's a possibility. When I'm backed into a corner I try this, never something I want to do but it has worked for other glitches so it might help you. . . Let me know how it goes.